# Programmatically perform a click function after adding children to a div in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function for search defined as

```
jQuery('#searchBtn').click(function()
   {
      var text = $('#searchbox').val();
      var searchUrl = "getrings.php?searchText=".concat(text);
      if(text.length > 2)
      {          
         jQuery('#sliderloading').removeClass('hide');
         jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:  searchUrl,
                    task: "save",
                    data: { 
                        ajax: "true",
                    },
                    dataType : 'json'
                }).done(function( msg ) 
                {

                    if( msg.status == "1") 
                    {
                        if(msg.data.length == 0)
                        {
                          alert('No rings found');
                        }                   
                        else
                        {                               
                          jQuery('.albums-div ul.slides').empty();
                          jQuery.each( msg.data, function( i, val ) 
                          {
                                jQuery('.albums-div ul.slides').append('<li> <input class="teringimage"  type="image" src="'+val['ringThumbNailImagePath']+'" name="checked" value="' + val['id']+'" data-my-info="'+val['ringSetName'] +'"  width="143" right="143"></li>');
                          }); 
                    }
               }
               else 
               {
                        alert("Error : "+msg.error);
                   }
                    jQuery('#sliderloading').addClass('hide');
             });
      }
      else 
      {
        alert("Search text is either empty or less than 3 characters");
      }
   });
```

I also have one jquery function as

```
  jQuery('.albums-div ul.slides').on('click','.teringimage',function()
    {
      }
```

First function, in a loop add some images and second function is run when an image is clicked.

However i want to do a little modification, after it adding images in first function

```
jQuery.each( msg.data, function( i, val ) 
                          {
                                jQuery('.albums-div ul.slides').append('<li> <input class="teringimage"  type="image" src="'+val['ringThumbNailImagePath']+'" name="checked" value="' + val['id']+'" data-my-info="'+val['ringSetName'] +'"  width="143" right="143"></li>');
                          }); 

//
```

I want to programmatically trigger click function on first element added To call the second function too.

How can this be achieved?

I have tried doing this

```
jQuery('.albums-div ul.slides').empty();
                          jQuery.each( msg.data, function( i, val ) 
                          {
                                jQuery('.albums-div ul.slides').append('<li> <input class="teringimage"  type="image" src="'+val['ringThumbNailImagePath']+'" name="checked" value="' + val['id']+'" data-my-info="'+val['ringSetName'] +'"  width="143" right="143"></li>');
                          }); 


         $('.albums-div ul.slides:first-child').trigger('click');
    and
    $('.albums-div ul.slides li:first-child').trigger('click');
```

nothing works

I want this call to work

```
jQuery('.albums-div ul.slides').on('click','.teringimage',function()
```

Comment: Use [`$(selector).trigger(eventType)`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: *on first element added To call the second function too.* i am confused..!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy i have a main div as .albums-div ul.slides in which i am adding elements <li> <input> in a loop. I want to trigger click function for first <li> <input>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [.trigger(event)](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/),

```
$('.albums-div ul.slides li:first-child').trigger('click');
```

Use,

```
$('.albums-div ul.slides li:first-child .teringimage[type=image]').trigger('click');
```

Comment: It is quite complex i am not sure how can i give u demo, i have edited my question, if u can read it again u will understand everything

Comment: http://thevowapp.com/webapp/test.php Check this link and try to search something like 3434

Answer (score 0):

Its simple

`$(selector).trigger('click')`

Comment: but to perform on first child.